# How to fix component layouting behavior in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hi, I'm writing an application using C#. I've designed the main form in such a way that it has two text boxes to capture username and password.

I want my window to open in maximized state but when I run the application the text boxes and labels move and they don't appear in the center (which is what I want).

This might be really simple but I can't figure out how to fix the component position in the form no matter the window is maximized or minimized.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the anchor for all the controls to none and they will stay centered. In contrast if you wanted them to move to the top left then you'd set the anchor the same.

Finally, if you set the anchor to Top, Left, Right, and Bottom they will stretch so that their borders stay the proper offset from the containers border.

Comment: great thanks .I thought I should set the anchor to Top, Left, Right, and Bottom to stay center. Guess I was wrong . thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this in the main form:

```
textBox1.Location = new Point((this.Width - textBox1.Width) / 2, this.Height / 2 - 10);
textBox2.Location = new Point((this.Width - textBox2.Width) / 2, this.Height / 2 + 10);
```

Replace textBox1 and textBox2 with your textboxes' names.
Haven't tested it, but it should work.